# Is it necessary to describe all the fields of an object in the interface if not all of them will be used?

Tags: typescript, oop, interface, solid-principles

**Is it necessary to describe all the fields of an object in the interface if not all of them will be used?**

Example:
I have a server response with the following structure:

```
{
  "A": "data",
  "B": "more data"
}
```

Do I need to type both properties **A** and **B**, if only **A** will be used in my program?

```
interface ServerResponse {
  A: string
  B: string
}
```

What principles \ rules \ patterns would I be violating if I wrote interface with only one property **A** that will be definitely used in my program?

```
interface ServerResponse {
  A: string
}
```

Comment: Could you provide a [mcve] of code that actually shows how you would be using your `ServerResponse`?  On the face of it, I'd say you should be able to omit any properties you don't care about from your interface, as long as you are just *receiving* values of that interface and you are mostly *reading* its properties.  If you start *sending* values and *writing* properties it's possible there could be concerns.  But there are all sorts of edge cases (like excess property checking, property key/value iteration), and it's hard for me to speak authoritatively without some use cases.

Comment: This is a pure theoretical question, what code you talking about? I already clearly described everything in the question.

Comment: I’m asking for examples of how you plan to use your interface, preferably with some code to illustrate it.  The answer to “do I need to include properties that I do not plan to directly use” depends on your use cases. I suppose without this information one could produce an answer which tries to list out various scenarios where it is fine and others where it is not. But such a heavyweight answer might miss your intended use case.

Comment: In short, you don't know the patterns or rules that regulate the use of interfaces in such cases.

Comment: That does not sound like a good-faith interpretation of my comments.  I was hoping for some scope narrowing here so I don’t have to write a book-length answer.  Since you are not inclined to do this, I will disengage and hopefully someone else will come along to provide an answer for you.  Good luck!

Comment: @flm The short answer is that you only have to define contracts that are meaningful to your application. It doesn't matter what the details are, the contract gives you a specific view of those details.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you only have to define contracts that are meaningful to your application. It doesn't matter what the details are, the interface gives you a specific view of those details.

Now, type safety won't be enforced at the boundaries of the application because the compiler has no idea which shape server's response will really have at runtime.

If you just cast the server's response to your interface you won't have runtime errors even if the response doesn't respects the contract at the casting site because there's no structural runtime validation of interfaces.

In order to have type safety at the system boundaries you have to validate at runtime before casting.

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful information, but you didn't answer the question. That's not the answer I'm looking for.

Comment: @flm I believe I did. You would not be violating any rule by only declaring the properties you are using despite not representative of the entire server's response. "Is it necessary to describe all the fields of an object in the interface if not all of them will be used"... No, it is not. The first sentence of my answer is the answer to that question.

Comment: Okay, I understand. But it sounds kind of unreliable. For example, if in the future there will be some changes in the code and we need other fields of the object, not specified in the interface, then the developer will have to go back to the backend code to understand what he sends there, each time wasting a lot of his time.
It seems to me that typing the full response from the server at the beginning is right, or use libraries for typing in runtime. 
Ideally BE shoud have API docs and client should have types in accordance with these docks.